# Do we have only one proof to Fermat's Last theorem?

Tags: soft-question, alternative-proof

Mathematicians usually get excited when alternate proofs are found to problems.

Fermat's last theorem is arguably the most well known math problem.

After Andrew Wiles monumental work, have there been any attempts to construct alternate proofs?

Wiles proof is supposed to be complex so it must be quite tempting to take another shot at FLT.

Is there any active research going on this?

Does any such proof exist?

Note that I am not asking whether elementary proofs of FLT exist. I know that they don't since such a proof is sure to make lots of news.

I am looking for proofs using other approaches than Wiles original one, maybe approaching it from another side etc

Comment: See the "General Mathematics" section of the arxiv. There are loads of alternative proofs for FLT there, as well as proofs (and the occasional disproof) of the Riemann hypothesis. Of course, these are "alternative proofs" in the sense of alternatives to proofs....

Comment: For anybody wo claims that he scribbled his proof somewhere on the side of a paper, but then the paper got lost: We don't believe you. Otherwise, nice question of which I do not have an answer.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I am looking for accepted and correct proofs. Of course there will be loads of incorrect proofs out there.

Comment: I don't think anybody found an argument for the FLT alternative to the [modularity of elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).